# How to expose a single module in PyPi after pip install

Tags: python, module, package, pypi

I'm trying to add a module I wrote to PyPi using distutils/setup.py etc. Everything went well, except that in order to access the module (after pip installing it) I have to do this:

```
from svdRec import svdRec
svd = svdRec.svdRec()
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
import svdRec
svd = svdRec.svdRec()
```

My file structure is like this:

```
svdRec
... setup.py
... README.md
... setup.cfg
... MANIFEST
... svdRec/
... ... svdRec.py
```

and my setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'svdRec',
  packages = ['svdRec'], # this must be the same as the name above
  version = '0.1.2',
  description = 'A Python3 Collaborative Recommendation Engine with Sparse Matrices',
  author = 'REDACTED',
  author_email = 'REDACTED',
  url = 'https://github.com/REDACTED', # use the URL to the github repo
  download_url = 'https://github.com/REDACTED', # Points to the github TAR file made by tagging
  keywords = ['recommender', 'sparse', 'matrix', 'recsys', 'svd'], # arbitrary keywords
  classifiers = [],
  install_requires = ['scipy','numpy'], # required packages
)
```

This is my first time trying to make a module installable, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated it on how to make the module exposable through a single call instead of needing to do

`from PACKAGE import MODULE`